# clearing console in cpp

Tags: c++, console

system("cls") doesnt work, it finishes the program without printing anything. 
the program works without it but doesnt look nice in the console without all the previous prints cleared. I've tried putting the command in different places but it doesnt matter where i put it the program finishes instantly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

float c, temp, eq;
char odp = 't';

int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Choose from what value you'd like to convert." << endl;
        cout << "Celsius = 1   ;   Fahrenheit = 0" << endl;
        cin >> c;

        if (c==1)
        {
           cout << "Insert Celsius value: ";
           cin >> temp;

           eq = temp * 1.8 + 32;
           cout << "It is " << eq << " degrees Fahrenheit." << endl;
           cout << "If you want to continue converting please insert: t" << endl;
           cin >> odp;
        }
        else if (c==0)
        {
            cout << "Insert Fahrenheit value: ";
            cin >> temp;

            eq = (temp * 1.8) - 32;
            cout << "It is " << eq << " degrees Celsius." << endl;
            cout << "If you want to continue converting please insert: t" << endl;
            cin >> odp;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please choose correctly" << endl;
        }
    }
    while(odp = 't');

return 0;
}
```

how i put the command and it finishes the whole program instantly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

float c, temp, eq;
char odp = 't';

int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Choose from what value you'd like to convert." << endl;
        cout << "Celsius = 1   ;   Fahrenheit = 0" << endl;
        cin >> c;

        if (c==1)
        {  system("cls")                                           //here
           cout << "Insert Celsius value: ";
           cin >> temp;

           eq = temp * 1.8 + 32;
           cout << "It is " << eq << " degrees Fahrenheit." << endl;
           cout << "If you want to continue converting please insert: t" << endl;
           cin >> odp;
        }
        else if (c==0)
        {
            cout << "Insert Fahrenheit value: ";
            cin >> temp;

            eq = (temp * 1.8) - 32;
            cout << "It is " << eq << " degrees Celsius." << endl;
            cout << "If you want to continue converting please insert: t" << endl;
            cin >> odp;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please choose correctly" << endl;
        }
    }
    while(odp = 't');

return 0;
}
```

i really dont know, thanks for the replies

Comment: Focus on fixing your bugs before you worry about looking "nice". (Most of us would consider the behaviour you don't want as perfectly normal, and actually prefer to have previous results stay visible.)

Comment: The second piece of code you posted works fine for me, once I added the missing semi-colon. You have an error in your while condition though, it should be `==` not `=`. What do you mean by finishing the whole program instantly? The console just closes? Also, I'm assuming you are using windows, since 'cls' is windows specific.

Comment: Also, your conversion from F to C is wrong! Very wrong!

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, on windows, the console closes after i press any button but doesnt run the code. I will change the while condition. Where is the semi colon missing? I dont get any bugs in my IDE.

Comment: `{  system("cls")` doesn't have an ending semi-colon.

Comment: @molbdnilo except the wrong F to C conversion i cant find any bugs and the program works for me

Comment: @ChrisMM It still doesnt work if i add the semi-colon

Comment: `<stdlib.h>`?  `<math.h>`?  Is your C++ compiler from the early 1990s?

Comment: I dont know i just started learning cpp, the compiler is gnu and IDE codeblocks.